# An expression of non boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected near )

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

The Query mentioned below works fine if I remove the Where clause.. Any Suggestions please??

```
SELECT     dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.BuchungsErfassungID, dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.QuellReferenz, dbo.MPProjektstamm.Projektnummer, 
                      dbo.MPProjektstamm.Projekttyp, dbo.MPProjektstamm.Matchcode AS ProjektMatchcode, dbo.MPProjektPhasen.PhasenID, 
                      dbo.MPProjektPhasen.Phase AS PhasenMatchcode, MPProjektleiterstamm.Personalnummer AS ProjektLeiternummer, 
                      MPProjektleiterstamm.Matchcode AS ProjektLeiterMatchcode, dbo.MPVKVertraege.VertragsID, dbo.MPVKVertraege.Vertragsnummer, 
                      dbo.MPVKVertraege.Bezeichnung, dbo.MPVKVertraege.KHKMandant, dbo.MPVKVertraege.Referenznummer, 
                      dbo.MPVKVertraege.Referenzzeichen, dbo.MPVKVertraegePositionen.Vertragsposition, dbo.MPVKVertraegePositionen.Matchcode AS PositionsMatchcode, 
                      dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.AnfrageID, dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.Kurzbeschreibung, dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.AnfrageText, dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.CardCode, 
                      dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.AdressMatchcode, dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.Referenz, dbo.MPPersonenstamm.Personalnummer, IsNull(dbo.MPVKVertraegePositionen.USER_Ratio, 1) AS 'Ratio',
                      dbo.MPPersonenstamm.Matchcode AS PersonalMatchcode,  dbo.MPVKVertraege.Projektnummer,
                      case dbo.MPPerioden.BezeichnungPeriode  when 'Januar' then '01.January' when 'Februar' then '02.February' when 'März' then '03.March' 
when 'April' then '04.April' when 'Mai' then '05.May' when 'Juni' then '06.June' 
when 'Juli' then '07.July' when 'August' then '08.August' when 'September' then '09.September' 
when 'Oktober' then '10.October' when 'November' then '11.November' when 'Dezember' then '12.December' 
End as 'Month',dbo.MPPerioden.BezeichnungJahr, 
                      dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf.Periode, dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.LeistungsTag, dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Menge, 
                      dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.MengeFAK as 'Horas', dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Aktivitaet, dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Memo, 
                      dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Freigabe, MPProjektLeistungserfassung.FakturaID, 
                      CASE dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.Status WHEN '1' THEN 'New' WHEN '2' THEN 'In Process' WHEN '3' THEN 'Customer Action' WHEN '4' THEN '3rd Party Investigation' WHEN
                       '5' THEN 'Closed' END AS 'Status',dbo.MPPerioden.Periode as 'Ind Periode',
                       T2.ContractNo,T2.Contract_Desc, ISNULL(T2.Q1, 0) AS 'Q1', 
ISNULL(T2.January, 0) AS 'January', ISNULL(T2.February, 0) AS 'February', ISNULL(T2.March, 0) AS 'March', 
ISNULL(T2.Invoiced_Q1, 0) AS 'Invoiced_Q1', ISNULL(T2.Q2, 0) AS 'Q2', ISNULL(T2.April, 0) AS 'April', 
ISNULL(T2.May,0) AS 'May', ISNULL(T2.June, 0) AS 'June', ISNULL(T2.Invoiced_Q2, 0) AS 'Invoiced_Q2', 
ISNULL(T2.Q3, 0) AS 'Q3', ISNULL(T2.July, 0) AS 'July', ISNULL(T2.August, 0) AS 'August', 
ISNULL(T2.Invoiced_Q3, 0) AS 'Invoiced_Q3', ISNULL(T2.Q4, 0) AS 'Q4', ISNULL(T2.September, 0) AS 'September', 
ISNULL(T2.October, 0) AS 'October',ISNULL(T2.November, 0) AS 'November', ISNULL(T2.December, 0) AS 'December', 
ISNULL(T2.Invoiced_Q4, 0) AS 'Invoiced_Q4',T2.Remaining_Year, T2.Comments, T2.Q1_Comments, T2.January_Comments, 
T2.February_Comments, T2.March_Comments, T2.Q2_Comments, T2.April_Comments, T2.May_Comments, T2.June_Comments, 
T2.Q3_Comments, T2.July_Comments, T2.August_Comments,T2.September_Comments, T2.Q4_Comments, T2.October_Comments, 
T2.November_Comments, T2.December_Comments                      
 , (SELECT Count(MPProjektLeistungserfassung.BuchungserfassungID) AS LCount 
              FROM MPProjektLeistungserfassung
            WHERE MPProjektLeistungserfassung.BuchungserfassungID = MPProjektBuchungserfassung.BuchungsErfassungID 
               AND MPProjektLeistungserfassung.Position > 0) AS Zuschlag                         

FROM         dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf ON dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.BuchungsKopf = dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf.BuchungsKopfID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPProjektLeistungserfassung AS MPProjektLeistungserfassung ON 
                      dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.BuchungsErfassungID = MPProjektLeistungserfassung.BuchungserfassungID AND 
                      MPProjektLeistungserfassung.Position = 0 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPProjektstamm ON dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Projektnummer = dbo.MPProjektstamm.Projektnummer INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vwMPProjektleiter ON dbo.vwMPProjektleiter.Projektnummer = dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.Projektnummer LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.MPProjektPhasen ON dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.PhasenID = dbo.MPProjektPhasen.PhasenID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPVKVertraege ON MPProjektLeistungserfassung.VertragsID = dbo.MPVKVertraege.VertragsID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPVKVertraegePositionen ON MPProjektLeistungserfassung.Vertragsposition = dbo.MPVKVertraegePositionen.Vertragsposition left outer JOIN
                      dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage ON dbo.MPHotlineAnfrage.AnfrageID = dbo.MPProjektBuchungserfassung.QuellReferenz INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPPersonenstamm AS MPProjektleiterstamm ON dbo.vwMPProjektleiter.Personalnummer = MPProjektleiterstamm.Personalnummer INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPPersonenstamm ON dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf.Personalnummer = dbo.MPPersonenstamm.Personalnummer INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MPPerioden ON dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf.Periode = dbo.MPPerioden.PeriodeJahr
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MP_USER_Retainers AS T2 ON dbo.MPVKVertraege.VertragsID= T2.ContractNo

where  DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())-1, -1)

order by dbo.MPProjektBuchungskopf.Periode
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to check the condition in `where` clause

```
WHERE  Dateadd(MONTH,Datediff(MONTH,-1,Getdate())-1,-1) = somedatecolumn -- Missed
```

Comment: Well, i need the results to show the data of earlier month, for ex. its 17/March/2015 today, when we run the report, it should show the data till Feb 2015. When i run the statement 'Dateadd(MONTH,Datediff(MONTH,-1,Getdate())-1,-1)', it gives me a value of 28/Feb/2015, so i thought of using it in where syntax. Can you help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`where DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())-1, -1)`

really means nothing. You will need to evaluate or equate with another value. For example,

`where dbo.mytable.mycolumn = DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())-1, -1)`